# Appirater popups not work when RevMobAds's fullscreen ads is behind it

Tags: iphone, ios, appirater, revmobads

In my app I used **Appirater** and **Revmobads**.Both work fine individually.When Appirater give me alert and I choose to rate app it will open appstore view perfect but when there is Revmob's **FULLSCREEN** are there **and on that Appirater popups ALERT** then rate app will not work and do nothing.For more detail i add image.

[image]

Note:I add FULLSCREEN ads on my app's rootViewController in

And How can i know appirater is called? is it possible to know?

`- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`

Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

This type of case comes seldom not continue so in that case you can do nothing. So close your app and then restart.